# Get fields from separately running jar

Tags: java, reflection

I know this is pretty generic, but is there a way for me to run a jar, then using a completely separate java program access fields from that running jar? I would like to ultimately set the text of a known `JTextField` (I know the name of the `JTextField` and class). I know how I could do this with reflection if it all ran as one unit, but I can't find any way to get an `Object` containing an instance of a running jar which is what you would need.

Comment: You want to write to a field of an Object in a separate JVM? Anything's possible but this might as well not be. This may be an XY problem, what is your true goal? Why not re-build or edit the existing Jar?

Comment: It's not an XY problem. My goal is literally to write to 2 textfields and perform a doClick() on a JButton in a running Jar. I can't modify the jar in any way. I am trying to automate a process

Comment: So your goal isn't necessarily to "access fields from [a] running jar", your real goal is just to automate filling out a UI in a Java Application; There exist automation tools to help with this already, you could simply have it focus the UI, tab to the fields you want, and type or enter to activate a button. However, I'll still answer your XY question since that approach is interesting and might apply to other problems.

Comment: The problem is this Jar is running on Ubuntu 11.10 on a custom processor board and I don't think I can install xdotool or find any other ways of simulating keypresses with a version of ubuntu so old. In addition, there is no keyboard, but instead a keypad that is read by a separate serial board that is connected to the jar via serial communication.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best solution, but you could override a class on the classpath of the running JAR without "actually" changing the JAR.

Lets say you want to modify `com.someone.elses.ClassA`. I would start by copying that class file and decompiling it, making the modifications, then recompiling it as my own version but with the exact same classpath.

When you run their JAR you can give your version of the class higher precedence on the classpath so it will be loaded instead of theirs.

```
java -cp "your.class:their.jar" path.to.their.Main
```

The program will then be running with your modified class, giving you access to whatever you need and perhaps reading from environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Each running java processes creates their own Virtual Machine with their class loaders and classes, they are also isolated by the OS itself.
In order to be able to communicate you could create ServerSocket in program 1 and listen for data/commands. And the second could connect to first using Socket and send defined commands which would be interpreted by the first one. Basically, you should use some communication channel and pass data between programs.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't modify the source code of the Jar. This makes it impossible doesn't it?

Comment: Almost everything is possible, but this would be non-trivial task, you could write an agent which would access loaded objects and change field values. You can start from reading on JVM Tool Interface https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/specs/jvmti.html